# What does "on the clothesline" mean?

Tags: plot-explanation, donnie-brasco

In *Donnie Brasco* (1997), Lefty asks Donnie about 90 foot boat for Santo Trafficante:

> Donnie: No, I'm working on it.
>
> Lefty: Don't tell me no. You got to get that boat. I reached out
> already. His man says, "Lefty, he loves boats. " I told him a 100-foot
> boat. I'm **on the clothesline** now.

What does "on the clothesline" mean?

Comment: It means, I suspect, that he's hung out on the line by promising something he may not be able to deliver.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It’s a riff on the common expression “to be hung out to dry”, which means he has been put in a difficult or impossible situation by his mob superiors.

https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/hang_out_to_dry

One hangs clothes on a clothesline, so Lefty is saying he was hung out to dry as on a clothesline.